# Why does my defined function return none?

Tags: python, recursion

These line of codes are part my program. I'm trying to make a simple calculator.

```
def num1():
    x = input('Enter your first number: ')
    
    if x.isdigit():
        return int(x)
        
    else:
        num1()
```

My program works fine until this function call itself and it will return None even i entered an integer.

Comment: Also, instead of using recursion for this you should use iteration. You should remove the `else:` part and add `while True:` as the first line of the function indenting everything else inside that.

Comment: @quamrana Thanks. My program works better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `return num1()` so the value obtained from the base case percolates back up to the initial call.